# Standard basis for $R^{2\times2}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi I am a bit confused about the standard basis for $R^{2\times2}$ I think it is

$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right],
\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\0&0\end{array}\right],
\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\1&0\end{array}\right],
\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\0&1\end{array}\right]
$$

Am I right?

Comment: Yes.  That's right.

Comment: I should add that the word *standard* is a bit loaded.  You have a perfectly reasonable candidate for the standard basis.